# Laravel 5.5 routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this strange issue with my routes in laravel 5.5, every time i try to open one of my routes i get `404` error

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

so i have to move that route on top of my `web.php` file, which is impossible in live app.

As much as I know my routes i do not have any function in my web.php file and all my routes refers to controllers.

I tried `php artisan route:cach` and i got this error:

```
λ php artisan route:cach
Route cache cleared!

In Route.php line 880:

  Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

any idea?

Comment: The error just means that you have a Closure in the api.php route called User. This means it can't be cached, but is not a problem if the route still works. Can you post the entire web.php, and an example URL you have tried which is returning a 404? (Closure comment here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319#issuecomment-73362932)

Comment: The artisan error posted relates to your api.php routes file, but you are experiencing a problem with your web.php routes. So you can ignore the error if your API routes are working. I have posted an answer to your web.php issue below.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problematic route the FrontendController@showpage route? If so:

```
// Show single product
Route::get('/{productslug}', 'frontend\FrontendController@showproduct')->name('showproduct')->where('productslug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
// Show single page
Route::get('/{slug}', 'frontend\FrontendController@showpage')->name('showpage')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

These two routes appear to be in conflict because they have the same where() clause, meaning the route can't distinguish between them.

The solution depends on what the difference between a {slug} and a {productslug} is. At the moment you are just saying any unlimited combination of words, numbers, hyphens and underscores.

If you can't distinguish between them with a regex, you should create a new route, but this will obviously change the URL.

```
// Show single product
Route::get('/product/{productslug}', 'frontend\FrontendController@showproduct')->name('showproduct')->where('productslug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: What is the difference between a slug and a product slug in terms of their regex?

Comment: slug is for showing pages, product slug is for showing product details

Comment: If you can't distinguish between them with a regex, then nor can Laravel. So I suggest you create a new URL for products at /product/{productslug} or if you want it to be less obvious you could do '/p/{productslug}' or even '/{productslug}/p'